# How to change the color chooser label of javaFX ColorPicker

Tags: javafx, color-picker

When you add a ColorPicker element, the color chooser label shows color text (as Gray here) for standard colors, other hexadecimal value. 
I want to show the custom text – like "Choose Color". Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With some discussions, it is found one can override the color label chooser by getting access to label as - get skin of color picker then get display label.